# Comparing two identical arrays returns false

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I want to compare two arrays with each other with this code:

```
if($jobids !== null){


    if (isset($_COOKIE["djsearchquery"])){


        $cookiequery[] = unserialize($_COOKIE['djsearchquery']);

        $arrayequal = ($cookiequery == $jobids);


        $consolelog = $cookiequery;
        $consolelog[] = $jobids;            
        $consolelog[] = $arrayequal;


        if($arrayequal == false){

            $response = array(
                'jobids' => $jobids,
                'markerpositions'  => $markerpositions,
                'consolelog'  => $consolelog
            );


            setcookie('djsearchquery', serialize($jobids), time()+3600);
            echo json_encode($response);

        }

    }
```

In the console the arrays are pictured exactly the same:
 [image: Picture of the console-log:]

Can someone explain to me why `$arrayequal` returns false? I don´t understand it.

Comment: `$cookiequery` is a 2-dimensional array, `$jobids` is only single dimensional. If you had used `$consolelog[] = $cookiequery;` (in the same way as you use `$consolelog[] = $jobds;` you would have seen this.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I got it now.

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
$cookiequery[] = unserialize($_COOKIE['djsearchquery']);
```

to

```
$cookiequery = unserialize($_COOKIE['djsearchquery']);
```

Comment: Omg.. that did the job =). Now I bang my head against a wall.. thank you

Comment: Great. Some times it happens with all of us :) Could you flag it as completed please